# Convert xy dataset to array

Tags: r

I have a dataset of time/value e.g.

```
> df <- data.frame(time=c(1,4,5,6), speed=c(100, 500, 600, 800))
```

I want to convert it to an array with one item per time tick:

```
> some_func(df, speed ~ time, step=1)
[1] 100 100 100 500 600 800
```

notice that a values for time == 2 and 3 were added.

Then I can use it in the cross correlation function.

Comment: Not the same values, but a linear approximation would be returned by `approx(df$time, df$speed, n=6)` that fills in linear interpolation for times 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the values that you want.

```
df$speed[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), c(diff(df$time), 1))]
[1] 100 100 100 500 600 800
```

Here, we use `rep` along with a vector argument to the second argument to return the indices of the desired vector for `df$speed`. We achieve this with `diff`, which will calculate the time period gaps and append 1 at the end to return the final value.

Comment: Thanks. It can be developed to do what I need. A.o. handling of decimal time and sub second resolution.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is by using the stepfunction to interpolate, as you wanted this in your above example.

```
sf<-stepfun(df$time,c(df$speed[1],df$speed))
sf(1:6)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with the ccf function and that is what I need. Is there a way to convert it to a vector?

Comment: The evaluated object sf(1:6) is a numeric vector. ccf(sf(1:6),sf(2:7)) works therefore.